# What are forbidden names for directories in Android's res directory?

Tags: android, naming

I recently added `res/raw/dictionaries/en-GB/wordlist.txt` to my Android project. It created an error. I eventually figured out that the directory name `dictionaries` was causing problems, I changed it to `dicts` and everything was fine.

Why is this name not allowed? Are any others not allowed? Is there a list of disallowed directory names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
you can see that:

> Qualifier name rules
>
> Alternative resource directories cannot be nested. For example, you
> cannot have res/drawable/drawable-en/.

Nested folders are not supported in the `res` folder, supports
only a linear list of files. But in the `assets` folders you can put an
arbitrary hierarchy of folders and files within it, because the contents of the assets folder are not considered resources.

You should not be able to something like `res/raw/dicts/en-GB/wordlist.txt`, but if that happened you probably failed to get the resource ID of the wordlist.txt (R.raw.wordlist)

The assets folder and the  raw  folder, are similar. Both
can contain raw files, but the files within  raw  are considered resources and the
files within  assets are not.

Comment: Interesting. I haven't tried accessing the files yet, but just changing the name of the folder seemed to make the error go away. Sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: probably is a bug.i made a test with the names you defined `res/raw/dictionaries/en-GB/wordlist.txt` and this case it gave me no error, but i was unable to access the wordlist by the resource id (R.raw.wordlist)

Answer (score 0):

As fars as I know, you cannot put any other files than those defined by Android, I thought you could only put the ones defined here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html
So it's surprising you can make /dicts ...

Comment: Nope. `res/raw` is yours to do with as you please.